# Hyper V cluster - one VM won't migrate

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, live-migration

We have a Failover Cluster built up on 6 blades, each running Hyper V.  Each box is running Server 2008 R2.

We've got a number of VMs running that all have the same basic config:

VHD stored on a cluster shared volume. 2 virtual NICs (1 for LAN connection and 1 for SAN connection).

All of our VMs will happily migrate between any other blade apart from one single VM which is running fine on it's current blade but will not migrate to any other location.

What could be the cause of it or where should I look to get a detailed error message as I can't seem to find much information logged in any of the logs.

Edit:

I know the usual culprit is mis-matching resource names.  We've already been there with the NICs named differently on some of the blades. As far as we can tell now everything looks to be identical on each bit of metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing posts on a few other forums we opted to remove the VM from the cluster.  Destroy the VM and then attach the underlying VHD to a fresh VM before adding it back to the cluster.  After this it all worked fine.

It's possible that this VM was created prior to all the cluster networks getting set up which I've noted can be a problem.  It's early days with my experience of Hyper V and it's migration... I'm missing the VMWare ESX that I used to work on with no problems!  I'll be fair, it's probably the case that we've made a mistake in the set-up but it would be nice if the error logging provided a little more info instead of just saying 'migration failed'.